# Apollo Server schema stitching using mergeSchemas, how to use a type from a separate schema?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm currently migrating a schema from using `graphql-js` definitions to an executableSchema using typedefs and resolvers. I'd like to migrate my codebase iteratively and stitch them together. So having some parts still use `graphql-js` and some parts use `gql` typedefs until I get around to doing the entire schema.

I'm running into an issue when I try to reuse an existing type in my typedefs.

For example my typedef might be:

```
type Query {
  customers: [User]
}
```

But the definition of the `User` type exists in my `graphql-js` schema. So it'll say `Error: Type "User" not found in document` even after the schemas are stitched.

Is this even possible or do I have to migrate anything that is related all at once?

Example:

```
// The original schema is created using graphql-js 
const oldSchema = new GraphQLSchema({query: ..., mutation: ...});

// The parts I'm slowly migrating to use graphql-tools
const newSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: ..., resolvers: ...});

// Then putting them together
const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({schemas: [oldSchema, newSchema]})
```

Comment: Interesting question, could you add the way you're running `mergeSchemas`? Not clear why you are talking about `executableSchema` but not about `makeRemoteExecutableSchema`.

Comment: @YevheniiHerasymchuk Thanks for the comment. The original schema is created using `graphql-js` so its created using: 

`const oldSchema = new GraphQLSchema({query: ..., mutation: ...});`

The parts I'm slowly migrating to use `graphql-tools` like:

`const newSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: ..., resolvers: ...});`

Then putting it together:

`const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({schemas: [oldSchema, newSchema]})`

Comment: Oh, I got it, your example code helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work with your "old schema" but in my project I merged them in following way...

```
import requireGraphQLFile from 'require-graphql-file';
import {makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server';

const schema1= requireGraphQLFile('./schema/schema1');
const schema2= requireGraphQLFile('./schema/schema2');
const schema3= requireGraphQLFile('./schema/schema3');

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
   typeDefs: [schema1,schema2, schema3],
   resolvers
});
```